# Estou com problema para exportar arquivo CSV em PHP

Tags: php, csv

Podem me ajudar senhores... estou com um código que está exportando dados para CSV, no entanto, o corpo da requisição está saindo junto no arquivo. Gostaria de exportar só os dados, sem o post inteiro. Segue abaixo meu código e como está saindo o CSV:

Arquivo list_users.php

```
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1",true);

if ($_POST['action']){
    if (isset($_POST["export_cli"])){
        $headers = ['ID', 'USUARIO', 'PERFIL', 'STATUS'];

        $dados = [
            [
                'ID' => '2',
                'USUARIO' => 'admin',
                'PERFIL' => 'ADMIN',
                'STATUS' => 'ATIVADO',
            ],
            [
                'ID' => '3',
                'USUARIO' => 'admin',
                'PERFIL' => 'ADMIN',
                'STATUS' => 'ATIVADO',
            ],
            [
                'ID' => '22',
                'USUARIO' => 'sittms',
                'PERFIL' => 'ADMIN',
                'STATUS' => 'ATIVADO',
            ],
            [
                'ID' => '341',
                'USUARIO' => 'DESATIVADO FCZGPMQ',
                'PERFIL' => 'ADMIN',
                'STATUS' => 'ATIVADO',
            ],
        ];

        $arquivo = fopen('php://output', 'w');

        fputcsv($arquivo , $headers);

        foreach ($dados as $chave => $valor) {
            $ID[$chave]  = $valor['ID'];
            $USUARIO[$chave] = $valor['USUARIO'];
            $PERFIL[$chave] = $valor['PERFIL'];
            $STATUS[$chave] = $valor['STATUS'];
        }

        foreach ($dados as $linha ){
            fputcsv($arquivo, $linha);
        }

        fclose($arquivo);
        header('Content-Type: application/csv; charset=utf-8');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Usuarios.csv');
    }
}


?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<link href="css/css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>FirstData</title>
 <script type="text/javascript">
        
 </script>
</head>

<body>
<center>
<div id="wrap">

    <div id="geral">
 
    <div style="clear:both; padding-bottom:10px;"></div>
         
             <table width="500" align="center">
                  <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" align="center" class="titulos">Busca de Usuarios</td>
                  </tr> 
            </table>
            <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" name="fDados" id="formulario">
            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="1" />
                <table width="500" align="center">
                      <tr>
                        <td width="150" align="center" class="titulos2"><strong>ID Usuário</strong></td>
                        <td width="250" class="bg"><input name="busca_id_lgn" id="busca_id_lgn" style="width:200px;"  type="text" value=""/></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td width="150" align="center" class="titulos2"><strong>Usuário</strong></td>
                        <td width="250" class="bg"><input name="busca_login" id="busca_login" style="width:200px;"  type="text" value=""/></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td colspan="2" width="250" align="right" >
                            <input name="busca_cli" id="busca_cli" type="submit" value="Busca Usuario" class="button"/>
                            <input name="export_cli" id="export_cli" type="submit" value="Exportar Usuarios" class="button"/>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                </table>
            </form>
            
            <table width="500" align="center">
                  <tr>
                    <td align="center" class="titulos2"><strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;ID</strong></td>
                    <td align="center" class="titulos2"><strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;Usuario</strong></td>
                    <td align="center" class="titulos2"><strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;Perfil</strong></td>
                    <td align="center" class="titulos2"><strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;Status </strong></td>
                    <td align="center" class="titulos2"><strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;</strong></td>
                  </tr>
                  
                  <?php //Resultado
                  
$count = 0;
            if($oksql){

                  while ($row = $conn->fetch()) {
                    $count++;
                    ?>
                     <tr>
                    <td align="center" class="titulos3"><strong>&nbsp;<?=$row['PKNI_LGN_ID'];?></strong></td>
                    <td align="center" class="titulos3"><strong>&nbsp;<?=$row['ATSV_LGN_LOGIN'];?></strong></td>
                    <td align="center" class="titulos3"><strong>&nbsp;<?=$row['ATSV_GAC_DESCRIPTON'];?></strong></td>
                    <td align="center" class="titulos3"><strong>&nbsp;<?=$row['ATIVO'];?></strong></td>
                    <td align="center" class="titulos3">
                        <strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="form_user.php?id=<?=$row['PKNI_LGN_ID'];?>"><img src="img/editar.gif" border="0" /></a>
                        </strong>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <?php
                  }
            }
                  ?>
            </table>
            
    </div>
</div>

<div id="overlay"></div>
<div id="report"></div>

</body>
</html>

o arquivo esta saindo assim:

ID,USUARIO,PERFIL,STATUS
2,admin,ADMIN,ATIVADO
3,admin,ADMIN,ATIVADO
22,sittms,ADMIN,ATIVADO
341,"DESATIVADO FCZGPMQ",ADMIN,ATIVADO

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<link href="css/css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>FirstData</title>
 <script type="text/javascript">
        
 </script>
</head>

<body>
<center>
<div id="wrap">

    <div id="geral">
 
    <div style="clear:both; padding-bottom:10px;"></div>
         
             <table width="500" align="center">
                  <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" align="center" class="titulos">Busca de Usuarios</td>
                  </tr> 
            </table>
            <form action="/teste/list_users.php" method="post" name="fDados" id="formulario">
            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="1" />
                <table width="500" align="center">
                      <tr>
                        <td width="150" align="center" class="titulos2"><strong>ID Usuário</strong></td>
                        <td width="250" class="bg"><input name="busca_id_lgn" id="busca_id_lgn" style="width:200px;"  type="text" value=""/></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td width="150" align="center" class="titulos2"><strong>Usuário</strong></td>
                        <td width="250" class="bg"><input name="busca_login" id="busca_login" style="width:200px;"  type="text" value=""/></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td colspan="2" width="250" align="right" >
                            <input name="busca_cli" id="busca_cli" type="submit" value="Busca Usuario" class="button"/>
                            <input name="export_cli" id="export_cli" type="submit" value="Exportar Usuarios" class="button"/>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                </table>
            </form>
            
            <table width="500" align="center">
                  <tr>
                    <td align="center" class="titulos2"><strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;ID</strong></td>
                    <td align="center" class="titulos2"><strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;Usuario</strong></td>
                    <td align="center" class="titulos2"><strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;Perfil</strong></td>
                    <td align="center" class="titulos2"><strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;Status </strong></td>
                    <td align="center" class="titulos2"><strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;</strong></td>
                  </tr>
                  
                  <br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: oksql in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\teste\list_users.php</b> on line <b>115</b><br />
            </table>
            
    </div>
</div>

<div id="overlay"></div>
<div id="report"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

O que ocorre neste caso é que após gerar o anexo e alterar os headers da requisição para fazer o download o processamento da página não é encerrado, por isso sai um arquivo com o CSV + o HTML que seria renderizado pelo navegador.

Isso pode ser resolvido encerrando a execução do script depois de anexar o arquivo no header de retorno. Seu código ficaria da seguinte forma:

```
fclose($arquivo);
 header('Content-Type: application/csv; charset=utf-8');
 header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Usuarios.csv');
 exit();
```